# Better way of handing opening python http server on multiple ports

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to open up python http server on 10 ports, and here is my current code.

```
self.server_thread = Thread(target=self.start_web_server)
        self.httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER[0]), MyHandler)
        self.httpd1 = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER[1]), MyHandler)
        self.httpd2 = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER[2]), MyHandler)
        self.httpd3 = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER[3]), MyHandler)
        self.httpd4 = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER[4]), MyHandler)
        self.httpd5 = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER[5]), MyHandler)
        self.httpd6 = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER[6]), MyHandler)
        self.httpd7 = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER[7]), MyHandler)
        self.httpd8 = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER[8]), MyHandler)
        self.httpd9 = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER[9]), MyHandler)
```

I was wondering if there is any better way to turn this into for loop.

```
def wait_for_message(self):
        print time.asctime(), "Server Starts"
        self.httpd.serve_forever()
        self.httpd1.serve_forever()
        self.httpd2.serve_forever()
        self.httpd3.serve_forever()
        self.httpd4.serve_forever()
        self.httpd5.serve_forever()
        self.httpd6.serve_forever()
        self.httpd7.serve_forever()
        self.httpd8.serve_forever()
        self.httpd9.serve_forever()

    def stop(self):
        self.httpd.shutdown()
        self.httpd1.shutdown()
        self.httpd2.shutdown()
        self.httpd3.shutdown()
        self.httpd4.shutdown()
        self.httpd5.shutdown()
        self.httpd6.shutdown()
        self.httpd7.shutdown()
        self.httpd8.shutdown()
        self.httpd9.shutdown()
        print time.asctime(), "Server Stops"
```

Also, this is my start and shutdown http server code.

This looks terrible, so would be nice if I also could turn this into a for loop.

Thank you.

Comment: Store all servers in a list, instead of holding a variable per server?

Comment: Honest question: Why would you do that (open ten instances of python http server)?

Comment: Because I have a program that sends message to 10 ports, and I need to make sure that all messages are transmitted correctly. That's why I had to open ten instances of python http server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the servers into a list:

```
servers = [HTTPServer((HOST_NAME, port_number), MyHandler)
           for port_number in PORT_NUMBER]
```

To start servers each in their own thread:

```
from threading import Thread

for httpd in servers:
    Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever).start()
```

To stop all servers gracefully:

```
import logging

for httpd in servers:
    try:
        httpd.shutdown()
    except Exception:
        logging.exception("Can't shutdown %r" % (httpd,)) # log exception here
```